# GWT sinkEvents in hosted mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

I extends a gwt celltable to create a custom celltable, i register the sinkevents ie onmouseover/onmouseout.
when you hover on the row of the table the row data is populated on the hover wiget(custom hover popup panel).
its works as it supose to do on development mode but once deployed on tomcat when you move the mouse over different rows on the celltable it
does not update the hover data on the popup panel unless you click away from the table(loose focus) and the hover again on the row.

```
public class MyCellTable<T> extends CellTable<T> {
    private Tooltip popup = new Tooltip();
    private List<String> tooltipHiddenColumn = new ArrayList<String>();
    private boolean showTooltip;

    public MyCellTable() {
        super();
        sinkEvents(Event.ONMOUSEOVER | Event.ONMOUSEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent2(Event event) {
        super.onBrowserEvent2(event);
        if (isShowTooltip()) {
            switch (DOM.eventGetType(event)) {
                case Event.ONMOUSEOUT: {
                    popup.hide(true);
                    break;
                }
                case Event.ONMOUSEOVER: {
                    popup.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
                    showToolTip(event);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToolTip(final Event event) {
        EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
        if (!Element.is(eventTarget)) {
            return;
        }
        final Element target = event.getEventTarget().cast();
        // Find the cell where the event occurred.
        TableCellElement tableCell = findNearestParentCell(target);
        if (tableCell == null) {
            return;
        }
        Element trElem = tableCell.getParentElement();
        if (trElem == null) {
            return;
        }
        TableRowElement tr = TableRowElement.as(trElem);
        Element sectionElem = tr.getParentElement();
        if (sectionElem == null) {
            return;
        }
        TableSectionElement section = TableSectionElement.as(sectionElem);
        if (section == getTableHeadElement()) {
            return;
        }
        NodeList<TableCellElement> cellElements = tr.getCells().cast();
        NodeList<TableCellElement> headers = getTableHeadElement().getRows().getItem(0).getCells().cast();
        popup.getGrid().clear(true);
        popup.getGrid().resizeRows(cellElements.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < cellElements.getLength(); i++) {
            if (getTooltipHiddenColumn().indexOf(headers.getItem(i).getInnerHTML()) == -1) {
                TableCellElement tst = TableCellElement.as(cellElements.getItem(i));
                popup.getGrid().setHTML(i, 0, headers.getItem(i).getInnerHTML());
                popup.getGrid().setHTML(i, 1, tst.getInnerHTML());
            }
        }
        // Here the constant values are used to give some gap between mouse pointer and popup panel
        popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
            public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
                int left = event.getClientX() + 5;
                int top = event.getClientY() + 5;
                if ((offsetHeight + top + 20) > Window.getClientHeight()) {
                    top = top - offsetHeight - 10;
                }
                popup.setPopupPosition(left, top);
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }

    public ArrayList<ReorderColumnsDetails> getColumnsHeaders(int index){ 
        ArrayList<ReorderColumnsDetails> column = new ArrayList<ReorderColumnsDetails>();
        NodeList<TableCellElement> headers = getTableHeadElement().getRows().getItem(0).getCells().cast();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            ReorderColumnsDetails clm = new ReorderColumnsDetails();
            clm.setHearder(headers.getItem(i).getInnerHTML().toString());
            clm.setItemIndex(i);
            column.add(clm);
        }    
        return  column;     
    }

    private TableCellElement findNearestParentCell(Element elem) {
        while ((elem != null) && (elem != getElement())) {
            String tagName = elem.getTagName();
            if ("td".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "th".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
                return elem.cast();
            }
            elem = elem.getParentElement();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Specify Name of the column's which is not to shown in the Tooltip
     */
    public List<String> getTooltipHiddenColumn() {
        return tooltipHiddenColumn;
    }

    /**
     * Set title to tooltip
     * 
     * @param title
     */
    public void setTooltipTitle(String title) {
        popup.setHTML(title);
    }

    public boolean isShowTooltip() {
        return showTooltip;
    }

    public void setShowTooltip(boolean showTooltip) {
        this.showTooltip = showTooltip;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: remove `getColumnsHeaders` from your code and add the code of  Tooltip, although a simplified working code showing just the issue should be great.

Comment: Hi the code works fine on dev mode, problem start when deployed on tomcat/webserver. The event are not been fired as they should. check onBrowserEvent2 which fires when the events changes onmouseout and onmouseover, but once deployed on webserver it does not fire.

Comment: onMouseOut is not firing only on production, why is that?